# React - How to filter a list without losing data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm able to filter the list to display the items I want. The problem is, my method of filtering actually alters the list rather than just display the items I'm after. I believe this is because I'm actually using setState to accomplish the filtering, so I need to use a method that keeps my original list and simply implements the filters rather than changing the state.

Here is the code for the functions I'm using to filter:

```
  filAll = () => {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos
    });
  }

  filActive = () => {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed)
    });
  }

  filComplete = () => {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed)
    });
  }
```

Someone had mentioned that I need my full list in props as opposed to state, but I don't really understand what that means or how to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform the filter inside the render function, without updating the state. You then have access to the filtered state when you render, but you never modify the original state.

```
class myComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let filteredComplete = this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed)
        // Use the filtered state here
        return ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need two state variables. `allTodos` and `todos`. Use `allTodos` to filter or process the data and `todos` will be displayed/rendered

```js
costructor(props) {
  const todos = [...props.todos];
  this.state = {
     allTodos: todos,
     todos: todos
  };
}

filActive = () => {
  this.setState({
    todos: this.state.allTodos.filter(todo => !todo.completed)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for those ones who are trying to perform this effect using hooks, see my suggestion below:

```
const data = [{id:1, description: "hey there" }, {id:2, description: "last meeting"}, {id:3, description: "thank god it's friday"}]

    export default function App(){
       const [items, setItems] = useState(data);
       const [term, setTerm] = useState('');

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Filter List React</h1>
          <input type='text' onChange={(e)=> setTerm(e.target.value)} />
          <ul>
          {items.filter((item)=> item.description.includes(term)).map(({id, description})=>{
            return <li key={id}>{description}</li> 
          })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      ); 
    }
```

Since `term` is initialized as an empty string, `filter` will match all items in the description property and then the `map` will retrieve all items. Once the user starts typing, `filter` will retrieve items which description matchs the term and the `map` will do the job.

I like this approach because there is no need to set and manage two states.

Comment: and how to to the same thing for a boolean to show true or false or both ??

Comment: How so? Can you give an example?

Comment: Tasks is a state objects with the IsDone attribute true or false. i want to filter them by All or isDone true or iSdone false. So three conditions to filter

Comment: I would do something like: 

const [data, setData] = useState(myData);

// showItems starts with nulll that returns all items
// you would need an input to set showItems value to true or false
// then the second condition in the ternary below would apply:

```const [showItems, setShowItems] = useState(null);

{showItems === null? 
      data.map((item) => ( <div>{item.something}</div> ))
      :
     data.filter(item => item.isDone === showItems).map((item)=> (<div>{item.something}</div>) )
 }```

Comment: And i add 3 buttons (All , done and not done) to change the show items state or what ?

Comment: Yeah, I believe this would do the job, take this concept and adjust according to your needs.